LSTM ODE prediction - choice of Batching/sequence length
I think using batching and related concepts properly would greatly increase the training speed and performance of my model, it would be great if anyone could help/clarify this for me!
The Problem:
Solutions to an ODE are given in a Dataframe where every 2 columns [x_i, y_i] represent a solution. (this is a small example)
   t  x0  y0  x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3
   1  10  15  13  55  34  46  55  44
   2  22  25  20  26  20  25  20  25
   3  20  35  32  35  50  35  30  65
   4  42  45  40  45  30  45  40  45
   5  50  55  50  55  50  55  50  55

Using a LSTM model I would like to predict the value of a solution at the next timestep (so the next row in the Dataframe)
The model (standard pytorch model..just for context):
class LSTMmodel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, out_size, layers):

        super().__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.input_size = input_size

        # Define LSTM layer
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers=layers)

        # Define linear layer
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, out_size)

    def forward(self, seq):
   
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(seq)
        pred = self.linear(lstm_out.view(len(seq), -1))

        return pred, hidden

My question is how would I go about batching in this context?
My understanding:
I choose a sequence length: seq_len = 2
I choose a batch size: batch_size = 3
One batch is a tensor of size (3,2,2) -- (batch_size, seq_len, the 2 columns))
This batch is fed through my network and I make 3 predictions, compare them to the labels do backpropagation and so on.
But is the batch:
   t  x0  y0  
   1  10  15  
   2  22  25  
 
   t  x0  y0   
   2  22  25  
   3  20  35  

   t  x0  y0   
   3  20  35  
   4  42  45  

OR
   t  x0  y0  
   1  10  15  
   2  22  25  
 
   t  x2  y2  
   1  22  25  
   2  20  35  

   t  x3  y3   
   1  20  35  
   2  42  45  

Is this a design choice or is one clearly better than the other?
Any help/tips would be great!
Thanks in advance,
kind regards,
Paul
